# In the bibliography, is it possible to adjust the page header to include the range of references?

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

In dictionaries (of all sorts), it is usually the case that one has some sort of range expressed in the page headers, for [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43691/how-to-display-unprinted-text-in-headers):

[image: Dictionary header]

I am writing a large document with Bibtex, `natbib`, and a numerical citation style. My bibliography spans many pages -- an [attempt at a MW] example is below:

```
\documentclass[openany,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}

@article{Bayes1763,
author = {Bayes, Mr. and Price, Mr.},
doi = {10.1098/rstl.1763.0053},
journal = {Philos. Trans.},
pages = {370--418},
title = {{An Essay towards Solving a Problem in the Doctrine of Chances. By the Late Rev. Mr. Bayes, F. R. S. Communicated by Mr. Price, in a Letter to John Canton, A. M. F. R. S.}},
url = {http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/53/370.short},
volume = {53},
year = {1763}
}}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
               Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@article(test2,}
@article{test3,}
@article{test4,}
@article{test5,}
@article{test6,}
@article{test7,}
@article{test8,}
@article{test9,}
@article{test10,}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2.25cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.4cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[classic]

\pagestyle{ruled}
\chapterstyle{ruled}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Page 1}
\leading{50pt} %Try and break onto a second page sooner.
I am an irritating \LaTeX{} test.\cite{Bayes1763,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9,test10}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

How may I display the range of citations in the header, i.e. something like "Bibliography --- [No. First on page]--[No. Last on Page]" above the page?

Comment: Is Biblatex an option? See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158775/dictionary-marks-in-biblatex).